# How to route messages to JMS MessageListener/Consumer when using Camel Resequencer?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-jms

**Scenario 1:**

I have Message producer and consumer and the flow of the application is as follows:

producer -> Queue -> Consumer

**Scenario 2:**
Now we have introduced Camel to re-sequence the messages.So The flow of application is as follows :

producer -> Queue1 -> Camel(Resequence) ->Queue2 -> consumer

**Question:**

Can we have do the Scenario 2 without using the Queue2 in camel. I want the messages to be consumed directly by consumer after the camel re-sequence step so the application flow will be as follows:

producer -> Queue1 -> Camel(Resequence) -> consumer

To send message:

```
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("mailbox", new Email("info@example.com", "Hello"));
```

Camel re-sequence

```
from("jms:queue1").resequence(header("myprop")).batch().to("queue2");
```

PS: I have used Message groups so that the messages to would be consumed by specific consumers, the solution should maintain this as well

Answer (score 0):

In that case you wouldn't implement the JMS consumer yourself but delegate message consumption to Camel's JMS component - you already did that with from("jms:queue1").

The logic that you would invoke in your consumer in "scenario 2" would then be moved to a Camel processor:

```
from("jms:queue1")
 .resequence(header("myprop")).batch()
 .process(new MessageProcessor());
```

The Camel processor working with the received message:

```
public class MessageProcessor implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Message in = exchange.getIn();
        Object body = in.getBody();
        // body contains the content of the received JMS message
        ...
    }
}
```

or shorter using Java 8 lambda syntax:

```
from("jms:queue1")
 .resequence(header("myprop")).batch()
 .process().message(message -> { 
    Object body = message.getBody();
    // body contains the content of the received JMS message
    ...
 });
```

This consumer-side logic should be transparent regarding message groups. The broker automatically choses the right consumer owning a certain message group when dispatching the message, you don't need to worry in your consumer-side code.